# SED - reverse matched pattern

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I have the following task:

**match all lines which end with a number and then reverse these numbers**

example:

```
romarana:qwerty12543
asdewfpwk:asdqwe312
asdj:asbd
asdewfpwk:strwtwe129
ooasodo:asbdjahj
```

should be:

```
romarana:qwerty34521
asdj:asbd
asdewfpwk:asdqwe213
asdewfpwk:strwtwe921
ooasodo:asbdjahj
```

What I tried:

```sh
sed -r "/[0-9]$/s/[0-9]{1,}$/$(rev <<< &)/" test.txt
```

**NOTE: you can ignore lines that don't end with the number for now.**

**NOTE: You can use awk,grep or any other tool**

Comment: It's not possible for the command substitution to refer to `sed` expressions. It's executed *before* `sed` runs.

Comment: This seems an awful lot like homework. I can't believe this is a real-world task.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you think is it possible to achieve my goal, even if I chain multiple tools together

Comment: In Ruby it would be simply `str.gsub(/\d+(?=$)/) { |s| s.reverse }`, which could be executed from the command line, and which no doubt is very similar to how it could be done in PHP, Python and other languages.

Comment: with GNU sed you can do `sed -E 's/([^0-9]*)([0-9]+)$/echo \1$(echo \2 | rev)/e'` but it assumes no other digits in the line and is not a robust solution, for example, single quotes in the input text will cause an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can also be done with `sed` alone, by inserting a separator character (let's take the number sign) before the number and then repeatedly moving the line's last digit before the separator:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]*\)$/#\1/;:b;s/#\([0-9]*\)\([0-9]\)$/\2#\1/;tb;s/#$//'
```

Comment: With sed when trying to come up with a magic character that can't be present in the input it's best to use `\n` (as a starting point at least) since by default that **cannot** be present in the line that sed is working on. If you pick `#` or some other character it's just a matter of time before that does show up in  the input.

Comment: @Ed Morton - My suggestion works independently of the separator character being present elsewhere in the input line.

Comment: That's fine, I've no idea what the characters in that script are actually doing individually or collectively so I'll take your word for it, but my comment still stands that `\n` is the best character to use when you're injecting one into a string to match on later.

Answer (score 7):

With `perl`

```
$ perl -pe 's/\d+$/reverse $&/e' ip.txt
romarana:qwerty34521
asdewfpwk:asdqwe213
asdj:asbd
asdewfpwk:strwtwe921
ooasodo:asbdjahj
```

The `e` modifier allows to use Perl code in replacement section. `$&` contains the matched portion.

Comment: This is great solution, learnt something new today. May be you could add this in your tutorial site :) if not added already

Comment: It is there in [perl one-liners](https://github.com/learnbyexample/Command-line-text-processing/blob/master/perl_the_swiss_knife.md#transforming)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with an `awk` command, as in the following `bash` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

(   echo romarana:qwerty12543
    echo asdewfpwk:asdqwe312
    echo asdj:asbd
    echo asdewfpwk:strwtwe129
    echo ooasodo:asbdjahj ) | awk '
        /[0-9]+$/ {                             # Lines ending in digits.
            num = txt = $0                      # Divide into text and num.
            gsub("[0-9]+$", "", txt)
            num = substr(num, length(txt)+1)

            revnum = ""                         # Build reversed number bit.
            while (num != "") {
                revnum = substr(num, 1, 1)""revnum
                num = substr(num, 2)
            }

            print txt""revnum" (from "$0")"     # Output text, reversed num.
            next
        }
        { print }                               # Not digits at end.
    '
```

It's pretty verbose, and could probably be reduced, but it does the job (you can get rid of the `from` output, that's just there so you can see it's working):

```
pax:~> ./testprog.sh
romarana:qwerty34521 (from romarana:qwerty12543)
asdewfpwk:asdqwe213 (from asdewfpwk:asdqwe312)
asdj:asbd
asdewfpwk:strwtwe921 (from asdewfpwk:strwtwe129)
ooasodo:asbdjahj
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `awk` could you please try following.

```
awk '
match($0,/[0-9]+$/,a){
  num=split(a[0],arr,"")
  for(i=num;i>0;i--){
    val=val arr[i]
  }
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) val
  val=""
  next
}
1
' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
romarana:qwerty34521
asdewfpwk:asdqwe213
asdj:asbd
asdewfpwk:strwtwe921
ooasodo:asbdjahj
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()` and null `FS` splitting `$0` into chars:

```
$ awk -v FS= 'match($0,/(.*[^0-9])([0-9]+)$/,a) {
    $0=a[2]; for (i=NF;i>=1;i--) a[1]=a[1] $i; $0=a[1]
} 1' file
romarana:qwerty34521
asdewfpwk:asdqwe213
asdj:asbd
asdewfpwk:strwtwe921
ooasodo:asbdjahj
```